# Separate a number into its digits and work with each digit

Tags: python

I've already divided a number into its digits by using the following:

```
n = input()    
z=[int(d) for d in str(n)]
```

I want to work with each digit separately, how can I do that?

Comment: "_Work with each digit separately_"... what do you mean? Just iterate over the list?

Comment: Also, basic tag should go.

Comment: just call the position in your `z` list, for example `z[0]` will be the first element of your list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`z` is a list so you can access each element :

```
>>> n = input()    
19894984
>>> z=[int(d) for d in str(n)]
>>> z
[1, 9, 8, 9, 4, 9, 8, 4]
>>> a=z[0]
>>> a
1
>>> a=z[5]
>>> a
9
```

and iterate trough it :

```
>>> for i in z:
...     print i
... 
1
9
8
9
4
9
8
4
>>> for i in range(len(z)):
...     print z[i]
... 
1
9
8
9
4
9
8
4
```

or directly do operation to have a new list :

```
>>> z2=[i*2 for i in z]
>>> z2
[2, 18, 16, 18, 8, 18, 16, 8]
```